# Function does not compile with Greater in it

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I have to speed up a matrix-calculation and would like to use `Compile` for it, though it fails and produces an unknown error message:

```
compiledFunc = 
  Compile[{{w, _Real, 2}, {v, _Integer, 1}, {hb, _Real, 
     1}, {vb, _Real, 1}}, Module[{h, hs, vr, hr},
    h = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.v + hb)]);
    hs = Boole@Thread[h > RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@hb}]];
    vr = 1./(1. + Exp[-((Transpose@w).hs + vb)]);
    hr = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.vr + hb)]);
    w + (0.01*(Outer[Times, h, v] - Outer[Times, hr, vr]))
    ], Parallelization -> True];

(*
  ==> Compile::argcompten: The comparison, Greater, is invalid for tensor arguments. >>
*)
```

Any idea how I can overcome this and/or speed it up?

**Update:**

According to the answers, the problem is that `Thread` is not compilable. Substituting it with `MapThread` indeed allows compilation. But then running the code gives another error. (I thought that since it is about the same piece of code, I won't start a new post.)

```
cFunc = Compile[{{w, _Real, 2}, {v, _Integer, 1}, {hb, _Real, 
     1}, {vb, _Real, 1}}, Module[{h, hs, vr, hr},
    h = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.v + hb)]);
    hs = Boole@
      MapThread[Greater, {h, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@hb}]}];
    vr = 1./(1. + Exp[-((Transpose@w).hs + vb)]);
    hr = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.vr + hb)]);
    w + (0.01*(Outer[Times, h, v] - Outer[Times, hr, vr]))],
   Parallelization -> True];

cFunc[w, v, hb, vb]

(*
   CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression 1.7+3.2 I should be a machine-size real number. >>

   CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 2; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
*)
```

Comment: You probably need to do the threading manually.

Comment: MMA is assuming that `h` is a tensor. How do you determine that a tensor is larger than some real number? You need to provide a metric in order for `Greater` to work.

Comment: @Matariki The purpose of the `Thread` is to thread the `>` over elements, so what you say is not a problem. However, `Thread` does not get compiled, and that is actually the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following seems to work based on what I assumed would be valid input.

```
compiledFunc = 
  Compile[{{w, _Real, 2}, {v, _Integer, 1}, {hb, _Real, 
     1}, {vb, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{h, hs, vr, hr, rr}, h = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.v + hb)]);
    rr = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@hb];
    rr = h - rr;
    hs = UnitStep[rr] Unitize[rr];
    vr = 1./(1. + Exp[-((Transpose@w).hs + vb)]);
    hr = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.vr + hb)]);
    w + (0.01*(Outer[Times, h, v] - Outer[Times, hr, vr]))], 
   Parallelization -> True];
```

**Edit:**

Since you are comparing to random reals we can safely assume none of the elements of `hb` will ever equal the pseudo-random values and remove the `Unitize[rr]` from the code. The above is for a more general comparison where equality can occur. Here is the cleaned up but less general version.

```
compiledFunc = 
  Compile[{{w, _Real, 2}, {v, _Integer, 1}, {hb, _Real, 
     1}, {vb, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{h, hs, vr, hr}, h = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.v + hb)]);
    hs = UnitStep[h-RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@hb]];
    vr = 1./(1. + Exp[-((Transpose@w).hs + vb)]);
    hr = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.vr + hb)]);
    w + (0.01*(Outer[Times, h, v] - Outer[Times, hr, vr]))], 
   Parallelization -> True];
```

As for the second part of the question, apparently `Compile` doesn't like `Boole` being applied outside of `MapThread`. OleksandrR explained why in the comments. `Compile` cannot work with the boolean tensor that is created by `MapThread`. You can replace the line with

```
MapThread[Boole[#1 > #2] &, {h, RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@hb]}]
```

and it should work.

Comment: How did you figure that out?? That `Boole` is not welcome inside `MapThread`.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I used `<<"CompiledFunctionTools`" and then `CompilePrint[compiledFunc]` and noticed a nasty call to `MainEvaluate` around the thing. Bringing the `Boole` inside fixed the issue. As to why this is the case, I'm not sure.

Comment: +1. Just wanted to add (as I think it is not necessarily obvious) that the reason why the `MapThread[Greater, _]` formation doesn't compile is that boolean tensors are not supported in the *Mathematica* VM. By placing `Boole` inside `MapThread`, boolean scalars generated by `Greater` get coerced into a real tensor, which is supported.

Comment: @OleksandrR. of course, silly me, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: when there is some error from using map in compile, with adding IntegerPart@ to the list that will be map, the error will not occur again. but why?

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not because of `Greater`, but `Thread`, [which is not compilable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1101/5).

```
MemberQ[Compile`CompilerFunctions[], Thread]
Out[1]= False
```

However, `MapThread` is! So you just need to replace the offending line involving `Thread` with:

```
hs = MapThread[Greater, {h, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@hb}]}];
```

and it compiles fine. Here's the complete function:

```
compiledFunc = 
    Compile[{{w, _Real, 2}, {v, _Integer, 1}, {hb, _Real, 1}, {vb, _Real, 1}}, 
        Module[{h, hs, vr, hr},
            h = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.v + hb)]);
            hs = MapThread[Greater, {h, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {Length@hb}]}];
            vr = 1./(1. + Exp[-((Transpose@w).hs + vb)]);
            hr = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.vr + hb)]);
            w + (0.01*(Outer[Times, h, v] - Outer[Times, hr, vr]))
        ], 
    Parallelization -> True
];
```

Comment: when I tried this, a) it didn't compile, b) I was asked to click on something  that took me to a page that says, *inter alia*: "If you have reached this page from Mathematica, it means that Mathematica has discovered that one of these checks has failed." :)

Comment: @acl Hmm... I have no clue. I tried compiling again in a fresh kernel and it had no problems. I've included the full function with the line replaced. Could you please try it in a new kernel? I'm using `8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 5, 2011)`

Comment: I diligently checked that post you have linked, before posting my question, but since I thought that `Greater` is the weak link, I did not check on `Thread`. The error message is thus rather useless in this case, one wonders why it does not point to `Thread` instead of the function that is to be threaded.

Comment: Of course the crash is not reproducible, it only happened randomly when I ran this! However, to see what I meant about compilation, try `SetSystemOptions[
 "CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" \[Rule] True]` before compiling, or `CompilePrint[compiledFunc]` after you have compiled it.

Comment: @IstvánZachar It didn't say anything because the check failed at `Greater`. If it had been something that was valid, then it would've definitely moved on and warned/complained about `Thread`. Try using `Boole@Thread[{1, 2, 3} == {4, 5, 6}]` instead. I get the error `Compile::extscalar: "Thread[{1,2,3}=={4,5,6}] cannot be compiled and will be evaluated externally."`

Comment: @R.M You only get that because you have just set the option `CompileReportExternal` as I described in my comment above. You are not normally warned about this.

Comment: @acl Oh, right. I forgot to mention that in my comment (too late to edit, so please note this, Istvan). Btw, I don't know what you (acl) mean is incorrect here... Hints?

Comment: @R.M maybe "incorrect" is not the right word, as your explanation is just fine (as is everybody else's). What I mean is that your `compiledFunc` emits the `extscalar` message, and if you use `CompilePrint` you'll see that it calls the main evaluator to do most of its work (ie, it's not actually compiled).

Comment: @R.M It's not `MapThread` that is the problem.

Comment: I have withdrawn my acceptance, since it now gives another error message, so I don't consider it "case closed".

Comment: @IstvánZachar My mistake. I forgot to include `Boole` in my `MapThread` function. Please try `Boole@(#1 > #2) &` as the function instead of `Greater`. It works for me (no errors with compile report turned on). If it works for you too, then I'll edit it in. Otherwise, I have no clue what else is incorrect...

Comment: I see Andy's edit covers that part.

Comment: It seems to work with the `Boole` inside `MapThread`. Any idea how to give a shared accept? Both you and Andy gave answers that helped me to understand what is going on.

Comment: @IstvánZachar if you like the `MapThread` approach better than `UnitStep` I suggest you accept RM's answer.  There isn't a huge speed difference as far as I can tell so its a matter of preference.

Answer (score 9):

`Thread` isn't compilable.

There are at least two ways of being warned that something is not being compiled: The first is to set `SetSystemOptions[ "CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal"->True]` (this gives `Compile::extscalar` messages upon compilation), and examination of the compiled function after the fact with `` Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"] `` followed by `CompilePrint[compiledFunc]`. This will show calls to the main evaluator.

To get this to compile, I find threading by hand the most readable approach:

```
compiledFunc = 
 Compile[{{w, _Real, 2}, {v, _Integer, 1}, {hb, _Real, 1}, {vb, _Real,
     1}}, Module[{h, hs, vr, hr}, h = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.v + hb)]);
   hs = Table[0., {i, Length@hb}];
   Do[
    hs[[i]] = Boole[h[[i]] > RandomReal[{0, 1}]],
    {i, Length@hb}
    ];
   vr = 1./(1. + Exp[-((Transpose@w).hs + vb)]);
   hr = 1./(1. + Exp[-(w.vr + hb)]);
   w + (0.01*(Outer[Times, h, v] - Outer[Times, hr, vr]))], 
  Parallelization -> True]
```

As for the rest of the code, I am sure it can be further optimised.